# Database rollback based on another thread result

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jpa, concurrency

I have a sequential processing of my business logic which includes:

1. Send the message to a remote server
2. Save that message to the database

**Sequential.java**

```
try {
   sender.send(message); // throws SendingException
} catch (SendingException e) {throw SomeException("Couldn't send.", e);}

dbService.save(message); // save only if successfully sent
```

I realised that I could improve the performance if I do those two tasks in parallel. One thread to send the message, and another thread to save it to the database.

**Parallel.java**

```
// send: 1st thread
executor.execute(() -> {
    try {
        sender.send(message);
    } catch(SendingException e) {throw SomeException("Couldn't send.", e);}

});

// save: 2nd thread
executor.execute(() -> dbService.save(message));
```

The problem with the `parallel` approach is that the `message` will be saved to the database even if the exception has occurred. Is there any way to prevent the saving if exception occurred, but still run those two tasks in parallel?

Maybe some kind of a trigger-based rollback.

Comment: Spring does not support out of the box rollback in muti threaded environment, but you can enforce it programmatically. Refer https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management-over-multiple-thread-1

Answer (score 1):

Once your data is saved and committed you can't rollback the transaction. Now you `send the message` from a different thread other than the thread from where you are `saving the message` to the DB. So, it is possible that your message saves to the `DB before the sending message` and in that case, if there is any `exception` during sending the message it is not possible to rollback. I will suggest using `CompletableFuture` like below:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // send message from here
    System.out.println("Msg send");
    return msg;
}).exceptionally(ex -> {
    // handle the exception
    System.out.println("Exception occour");
    return "";
}).thenAccept((msgTosave) -> {
    if (!msgTosave.isEmpty()) {
        // save your msg to db here
        System.out.println("Msg To save : " + msgTosave);
    }
});
```